# changing date format of entire column in python

Tags: python

i have a dataset naming transactiondata . Under this dataset format of date column is integer. Do i have to import something in jupyter first to change the format , what will be the code to do so?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldTm.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post code as images (not screenshots or close-up shots of your screen); paste the code in.

Comment: Beyond that: how should we know how those numbers represent dates? Where did you get this dataset, how did you load it? What program originally produced it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that your data represents a date and time in unix format, you need to know in what units this data is represented (in seconds, minutes, hours, days)

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'date':  [43390, 43599, 43605]}
df = pd.DataFrame(values)

# unit='h' - means in hour, other options (s, m, d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='h')

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

Prints

```
                 date
0 1974-12-13 22:00:00
1 1974-12-22 15:00:00
2 1974-12-22 21:00:00
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```